# Four Directions #13 - Where and what am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, geography

> To the North lies a place full of crumpets and tea.
>
> Also to the North, they say Kawaii.
>
> Another place to the North is very bumpy.
>
> Again to the North, you'll get very sweaty.

Where am I?

Comment: Haha I like this one!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you at the

> South Pole?

Because

> Everywhere is to the North...

To the North lies a place full of crumpets and tea.

> The UK, which is North of the South Pole.

Also to the North, they say Kawaii.

> Japan, which is North of the South Pole.

Another place to the North is very bumpy.

> The Himalayas, which are North of the South Pole.

Again to the North, you'll get very sweaty.

> The Sahara Desert, which is North of the South Pole.

I apologize in advance if this is incorrect!!

Comment: Perfect! :D will accept in 5 mins